# Smartpointers do not work well with a generic TObjectlist in Delphi

Tags: delphi, smart-pointers, generic-list, spring4d

I am testing smart-pointers in Delphi 10.3 Rio using Spring4D. Here is my test program. I created a generic `TObjectList` and I want to add simple `TObject`s to this list using `Shared.Make(TTestObj.Create)`. The problem is that whenever I add an object to the List, the previous object is released. See the output of my program. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
program TestSmartPointer;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Spring,
  Diagnostics,
  Classes,
  SysUtils,
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TTestObj = class
  private
    FDescription: string;
  public
    property Description: string read FDescription write FDescription;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
  TTestList = class(TObjectList<TTestObj>)
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  LISTITEMCOUNT: integer;
  LISTCOUNT: integer;

procedure Test_SmartPointer;
begin
  Writeln('SmartPointer test started');
  var lTestList := Shared.Make(TTestList.Create)();
  lTestList.OwnsObjects := false;
  for var i := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    var lTestObj := Shared.Make(TTestObj.Create)();
//    var lTestObj := TTestObj.Create;
    lTestObj.Description := i.ToString;
    Writeln('TestObj added to Testlist with description ' + lTestObj.Description);
    lTestList.Add(lTestObj);
  end;
  Writeln('SmartPointer test finished');
end;

{ TTestObj }

destructor TTestObj.Destroy;
begin
  Writeln(format('TTestObj with description %s is destroyed', [FDescription]));
  inherited;
end;

{ TTestList }

destructor TTestList.Destroy;
begin
  Writeln('TTestList is destroyed');
  inherited;
end;

begin
  Test_SmartPointer;
  Readln;
end.
```

[image: Output]

Comment: If you are using spring, why would you use generics.collections? Surely you should use spring collections. And then you don't need smart pointers at all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok, that's a good answer. I will try this, thanks.

Comment: Looking again, what I say is reasonable for the collection, but may not be relevant for its members.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if you use TCollections.CreateObjectList<T> when creating IList<T> the members are automatically released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `TObjectList` holds raw `TTestObj` object pointers, not the `IShared<TTestObj>` interfaces that `Shared.Make<T>()` returns.

In `var lTestList := Shared.Make(TTestList.Create)();`, you are creating an `IShared<TTestList>` (a `reference to function: TTestList`) that wraps a `TTestList` object you are creating.  You are invoking `()` on the `IShared`, which calls the function to return the raw `TTestList` object pointer.  Which is OK in this example, because the `IShared` will be held in a hidden variable for the lifetime of `Test_SmartPointer()`, thus its refcount is 1, keeping the `TTestList` alive.

In `var lTestObj := Shared.Make(TTestObj.Create)();` you are doing the same thing, this time for an `IShared<TTestObj>` returning an `TTestObj` object pointer.  However, when `lTestObj` goes out of scope at the end of each loop iteration, the refcount of the `IShared` is decremented.  Since there are no further references to that interface, its refcount falls to 0, destroying the object behind the `IShared`, which in turn destroys its associated `TTestObj` object, leaving the `TObjectList` with a dangling `TTestObj` pointer (but you don't experience any crashes with that, since you are not accessing the stored `TTestObj` objects in any way, not even in the `TObjectList` destructor due to `OwnsObjects=false`).

You need to change `TTestList` to hold `IShared<TTestObj>` elements instead of `TTestObj` elements (in that case, you should use `TList<T>` instead of `TObjectList<T>`), and get rid of the `()` invocations on the `IShared` interfaces when calling `Shared.Make()`:

```pascal
program TestSmartPointer;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Spring,
  Diagnostics,
  Classes,
  SysUtils,
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TTestObj = class
  private
    FDescription: string;
  public
    property Description: string read FDescription write FDescription;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TTestList = class(TObjectList<IShared<TTestObj>>)
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  LISTITEMCOUNT: integer;
  LISTCOUNT: integer;

procedure Test_SmartPointer;
begin
  Writeln('SmartPointer test started');
  var lTestList := Shared.Make(TTestList.Create);
  for var i := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    var lTestObj := Shared.Make(TTestObj.Create);
    lTestObj.Description := i.ToString;
    Writeln('TestObj added to Testlist with description ' + lTestObj.Description);
    lTestList.Add(lTestObj);
  end;
  Writeln('SmartPointer test finished');
end;

{ TTestObj }

destructor TTestObj.Destroy;
begin
  Writeln(Format('TTestObj with description %s is destroyed', [FDescription]));
  inherited;
end;

{ TTestList }

destructor TTestList.Destroy;
begin
  Writeln('TTestList is destroyed');
  inherited;
end;

begin
  Test_SmartPointer;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Since Delphi has no garbage collector and ARC has been removed I was looking for a general structure to automatically free objects. My impression from smartpointers is that it's a bit too complicated to be used as  an easy-to-use general stucture for automatically freeing objects.

Comment: "*and ARC has been removed*" - well, not yet anyway, not until RAD Studio 10.4 is released.  Not that it matters, as this issue exists in previous versions too, for non-ARC platforms like Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that works (thanks to Remy Lebeau). Since Delphi has no garbage collector and ARC has been removed I was looking for a general structure to automatically free objects. My impression from smartpointers is that it's a bit too complicated to be used as  an easy-to-use general stucture for automatically freeing objects.

```
program TestSmartPointer;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Spring,
  Diagnostics,
  Classes,
  SysUtils,
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TTestObj = class
  private
    FDescription: string;
  public
    property Description: string read FDescription write FDescription;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
  TTestList = class(TList<IShared<TTestObj>>)
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

procedure Test_SmartPointer;
var
  lTestList: IShared<TTestList>;
  lTestObj: IShared<TTestObj>;
  i: integer;
begin
  Writeln('SmartPointer test started');
  lTestList := Shared.Make(TTestList.Create);
  for i := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    lTestObj := Shared.Make(TTestObj.Create);
    lTestObj.Description := i.ToString;
    Writeln(format('TestObj with description %s added to Testlist', [lTestObj.Description]));
    lTestList.Add(lTestObj);
  end;
  for lTestObj in lTestList do
  begin
    writeln(lTestObj.Description);
  end;

  Writeln('SmartPointer test finished');
end;

{ TTestObj }

destructor TTestObj.Destroy;
begin
  Writeln(format('TestObj with description %s is destroyed', [FDescription]));
  inherited;
end;

{ TTestList }

destructor TTestList.Destroy;
begin
  Writeln('TTestList is destroyed');
  inherited;
end;

begin
  Test_SmartPointer;
  Readln;
end.
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub5Xp.png)

Comment: You did not need to change your `Test_SmartPointer()` procedure (except to remove the assignment of `lTestList.OwnsObjects := false;`).  Once you changed `TTestList` to use `TList<IShared<TTestObj>>` instead of `TObjectList<TTestObj>`, the rest of your code was fine.

Comment: You might not have noticed the brackets after Shared.Make(TTestObj.Create)(). That was the real problem.

Comment: No, I didn't notice that, thanks. I have tweaked the wording of my answer. But that doesn't change the core issue described by my answer. The original code was still storing raw `TTestObj` pointers into the list rather than the `IShared<TTestObj>` interfaces.